# How pass multiple values to report viewer data-source

Tags: visual-studio-2012, client, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to develop client side report in visual studio 2012. My report is working fine with different selection criteria variables. I am getting error while multi selected list values in filters. passing values as

```
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="0" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$ddlStartHour" Name="StartHour" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="0" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$ddlStartMinute" Name="StartMinute" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="2012-11-01" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$txtStartDate" Name="DateFrom" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="23" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$ddlEndHour" Name="EndHour" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="59" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$ddlEndMinute" Name="EndMinute" />
        <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="2012-11-01" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$txtEndDate" Name="DateTo" />

        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="5027" Name="AgentList" SessionField="AgentList" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

In query in need AgentId as SkillTargetID IN (@AgentList). when I pass single value as 5000 its working fine and showing records. But when I pass multiple values as 5000,5001,5002 etc then got error. Any suggestion to pass multiple values to report viewer.
I had tried with

5000,5001,5002

'5000','5001','5002'

(5000,5001,5002)

('5000'),('5001'),('5002')

[image: Error]

I am trying this on visual studio 2012, Sql server 2008 r2 and .net framework 4.5.

Comment: Well.. Can you write some code or some words about your actions? Do you create `List<int>` and pass it to dataset? Where do you want to show this data? in the table?

Comment: I am trying to pass these values to report viewer data source.I am passing filters values in report viewer data shource as <SelectParameters>
<asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="0" FormField="ctl00$MainContent$BasicFilterControls$ddlStartHour" Name="StartHour" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="5027" Name="AgentList" SessionField="AgentList" />
        </SelectParameters> these filter are working fine with single value in AgentList when I pass multi selected values in AgentList then it replies with error as failed when converting ot nvarchar value to data type int.

Comment: What about another questions?

Comment: I want to show this data in report. I am getting problem only in multi-selected agent list parameter. I want to know that how can I pass multi selected values to my query WHERE clause IN (@AgentList)

Comment: What are you using to store data before you pass it to the report - DataTable or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sill I couldn't find any proper solution but I solve my problem by changing DataSource SelectCommand query. On report refresh button_click I just change MyDataSource.SelectCommand query as

```
string AgentIds = "5000,5001,5002";
        MyDataSource.SelectComamnd = "Select * from Agent where AgentId IN ('" + AgentIds + "')";
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

and it works. If anyone find a batter solution to add multiple values to DataSource variable then please update me.